# How to check if part of a string is in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
user_input = "";
answer = "";

Array.greeting = ["hi", "hello"]
Array.names = ["john","james"]

user_input = document.getElementById('user_input').value.toLowerCase();
document.getElementById('text_input').innerHTML = user_input;

documnet.getElementById('say_something').innerHTML = say;
if(""){}
else{}
if(Array.greeting.includes(user_input) > 0){
    say = "Hello";
}
if(Array.names.includes(user_input) > 0){
    say = "User";
}
```

This is what i understand and have got up and running with correct outputs but how could i use input "hi john" and get output of "Hello User" with out baking it into an array?

Comment: `documnet` is a typo. `say` isn’t defined when that line runs.

Comment: You realise you're adding properties to the `Array` object, rather than declaring variables? Assuming you know this, why are you taking that approach?

Comment: This isn't actually a part of the code but rather, made in a hurry.
`if(Array.greeting.includes(user_input) > 0){
    say = "Hello";
}
if(Array.names.includes(user_input) > 0){
    say = "User";
}`
I'd need to combine these two so that the answer is either from both or from a combined goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```js
var greetings = ["hi", "hello"];
var names = ["john","james"];

submit.onclick = function () {
    // Split input into words, and convert that array to a Set for fast lookup
    var words = new Set(user_input.value.split(/\s+/));
    // Choose a greeting that is not among the input words.
    // If all of them occur in the input, take the first greeting word
    var greeting = greetings.find( greeting => !words.has(greeting)) || greetings[0]; 
    // Choose a name that is not among the input words (or take the first)
    var name = names.find( name => !words.has(name)) || names[0];
    // Output with textContent (not innerHTML!)
    text_input.textContent = user_input.value;
    say_something.textContent = greeting + ' ' + name;
}
```

```html
Input: <input id="user_input"><button id="submit">Submit</button><br>

You said: <span id="text_input"></span><br>
Reply: <span id="say_something"></span>
```

Obviously, when you enter both "hi" and "hello", the code will not find a greeting to use. In that case it uses the first greeting in the array ("hi"). The same principle applies for the names.

Comment: Not quite what i expected but a HUGE thank you! This helps with my development. May the force be with you :D

Answer (score 0):

Let's simplify your requirement as:
You want to check if any element of an array "arr" contains part of string "s".

```
var check = function(arr, s) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (s.indexOf(arr[i]) > -1) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: `Array.Greeting = ["hi", "hello"];
Array.Names = ["john","james"];

if(Array.Greeting.includes(user_input) > 0){
    say = "Hello.";
}
if(Array.Names.includes(user_input) > 0){
    say = "User";
}`
This does the same for me but how can i check if `user_input` has value(s) from both arrays? For example "hi john".

Comment: extending my solution, `if (check(Array.greeting, user_input) && check(Array.names, user_input)) { say = "Hello User" }`